# Google Flexible Environment django gunicorn nginx static files

Tags: django, google-app-engine, static, django-templates, gunicorn

Running a Django project Google Flexible Environment with Gunicorn as entry-point so that I can use geventworkers.
Cant seem to figure out how to server the static files properly.
I have set `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` and `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` in Django settings. 
I've also ran `manage.py collectstatic` and the files do get copied correctly, yet my django rest framework swagger cant find its files.

For the convenience I had already added `TEMPLATES` to my settings as well.
This used to work before I started using geventworkers.

Im trying to get nginx to serve the files, but I cant seem to edit the nginx config. Of the docker that it runs by default.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'rest_framework.templates',
            'rest_framework_swagger.templates',
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'website'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn doesn't serve static content, so you have to create a Google Cloud Storage bucket to serve static content.

Create a bucket and upload the static files.

```
gsutil mb gs://<your-gcs-bucket>
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://<your-gcs-bucket>
gsutil rsync -R static/ gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/static
```

In `settings.py` set the value of `STATIC_URL` as following:

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/<your-gcs-bucket>/static/'
```

You can folow [step by step guide](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#deploy_the_app_to_the_app_engine_flexible_environment) to see how to deploy the app to the App Engine flexible environment.

Comment: I mean yeah I know this works but I am trying to find a solution that I mean be able to get the default nginx config to pick up my static files

Comment: @RoseBlax what you are trying to achieve is not related to your original post. Either edit your post so it's gonna be more clear what you want to achieve or post another question.